# Photoshop CC 2017 keeps crashing on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, crash, adobe-photoshop, macos-catalina

I have installed Photoshop CC 2017 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.2. I've been using it for a while and it was fine. But after a while, my Photoshop doesn't work anymore, it crashes everytime I try to open it. Here's the crash log: https://pastebin.com/njzBLxbK

Other Adobe applications work fine, only Photoshop is affected. I've tried resetting preferences, restarting my Mac and several other solutions, but none of them seem to work.

Can someone please help me? I'm using it for my work and really need help now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC 2017 is simply not supported on Catalina.

From Adobe KB - [Which Photoshop versions are compatible with macOS Catalina?](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/kb/photoshop-and-macos-catalina.html)

> Older versions use 32-bit licensing components and installers. Therefore, they cannot be installed and activated after upgrading to macOS Catalina. Upgrading to macOS Catalina with an older version already installed on your computer may allow the application to function in some capacity; however, you will not be able to reinstall or activate the application after the macOS upgrade.

CC2019 works with some issues, CC20 is recommended.
As Adobe CC is subscription-based, you've already paid for your updates, so simply update to CC20.

Comment: I was using it for a while and it worked fine. If it isn't supported on Catalina then I wouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: it ***isn't*** supported on Catalina at all - the Adobe KB says exactly that. It says you might get away with it for a while, but won't be able to run any of the 32-bit components. Why don't you just update? The 2020 has lots of new AI in it, I don't know what's holding you back.